# My codeigniter project redirecting to www when i am accessing it in local pc

Tags: codeigniter

When i am trying to run a codeigniter project in my localhost it is redirecting me to **www.localhost/projectname.**

And Showing Errors.

Comment: check your virtual host setup and base url

Comment: try to remove www. in baseurl

Comment: Show us you base_url in config.php

Comment: if (!empty($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"])) {

 $http_host = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];

    switch($http_host)

    {

        case '192.168.0.103':

   
   $config['site_folder'] = '/delux/';

  break;

Comment: Pointed URL in bold style to make clear visibility.

Comment: @AbdulWaheed .. It doesn't help and that's not what we are talking about here .. that's the url that its redirected to and we want to see the one in config.php first and want to see what is triggering the redirect.

Comment: @DebasisKr.Acharya : check your documentroot/.htaccess file....if possible post here. In same file might be added....

Comment: Hi BK, here is the htaccess details

Comment: RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l 
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|uploads|public|robots\.txt) 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php
# To redirect all users to access the site WITH the 'www.' prefix,
# (http://example.com/... will be redirected to http://www.example.com/...)
# uncomment the following:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]